# How to convert my sql result to below dictionary format in python?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I have a sample results like this one:

```
[{'BUSINESS_UNIT': 'Communications',
  'PROCESS': 'Contributions',
  'GEO': 'Europe',
  'MARKET': 'Global',
  'COUNTRY': 'France',
  'RPTG_QTR': '2018 Q3'},
 {'BUSINESS_UNIT': 'Communications',
  'PROCESS': 'Contributions',
  'GEO': 'Global',
  'MARKET': 'Global',
  'COUNTRY': 'France',
  'RPTG_QTR': '2018 Q4'}]
```

I tried several approach like using defaultdict, but still no good.

```
for row in surveys: #Format the results 
    result = {'BU':{row['BUSINESS_UNIT']:{'Process':{row['PROCESS']:'GEO'}}}}


    #print(row['PROCESS'])
   #print(row)

print(type(result))  
result
```

I would like to convert it into this:

```
     Business Unit: { 
          'Communication': {
                   Process: {
                           'Contributions': {
                                     GEO: {
                                           'Europe': {...}
                                     GEO: :
                                           'Global': {...}
```

Comment: What do you mean GEO : { 'Europe' : {...} and again GEO?? duplicated keys?

Comment: Hi @Lamanus, oh yeah, my mistakes it should be only one label for Geo.